# Pandas Dataframe Not Working As Expected

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas on a table at this link:

```
http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/stats/byposition?pos=QB&conference=NFL&year=season_2014&sort=49&timeframe=All
```

I'm trying to create player objects out of each (relevant) row.  So I want the 3rd row through the end, and I'm using a bunch of different fields to construct a player object, including name, team, passing yards, etc.

Here's my attempt:

```
def getAllQBs():
    QBs = []
    table = pd.read_html(requests.get(QB_LINK).content)[5]
    finalTable = table[2 : ]
    print(finalTable)

    for row in finalTable.iterrows():
        print(row)
        name = row[0]
        team = row[1]
        passingYards = row[7]
        passingTouchdowns = row[10]
        interceptions = row[11]
        rushingYards = row[13]
        rushingTouchdowns = row[16]
        rushingFumbles = row[19]
        newQB = QB(name, team, rushingYards, rushingTouchdowns, rushingFumbles, passingYards, passingTouchdowns, interceptions)
        QBs.append(newQB)
        print(newQB.toString())
    return QBs
```

Passing yards is the 8th element from the left in the row, so I thought I'd access it using `row[7]`.  However, when I run this function, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 64, in main
    getAllQBs()
  File "main.py", line 27, in getAllQBs
    passingYards = row[7]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It looks like I'm inadvertently using columns.  However, I used `DataFrame.iterrows()`, which I thought would take care of this...

Any ideas?

Thanks,
bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterrows()` generates tuples of the form `(index, Series)`, where Series is the row data you're trying access.  In this case where your index isn't meaningful, you can unpack it to a dummy variable, like this.

```
for (_, row) in finalTable.iterrows():
    .....
```